# Add Font crashes my app

Tags: android, fonts, crash, runtime-error, typeface

I try to add a font in my application, but every time my application crashes.

My font is a .ttf inserted correctly in the `assets\font` folder.

My Java code is:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView myTextView1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textBox1);
       // Typeface typeFace= Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Intellecta_Digital.ttf");
        Typeface typeFace1= Typeface.SERIF;
        myTextView1.setTypeface(typeFace1);

        TextView myTextView2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textBox2);
        Typeface typeFace2= Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD;
        myTextView2.setTypeface(typeFace2);

        TextView myTextView3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textBox3);
        Typeface typeFace3= Typeface.MONOSPACE;
        myTextView3.setTypeface(typeFace3);

        TextView myTextView4=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textBox4);
        AssetManager mngr =getAssets();
        Typeface typeFace4= Typeface.createFromAsset(mngr, "fonts/font_example.ttf");
        myTextView4.setTypeface(typeFace4);
    }
}
```

My XML is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:text="Font Typeface"
        android:id="@+id/textBoxStandard" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:text="Font Typeface"
        android:id="@+id/textBox1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:text="Font Typeface"
        android:id="@+id/textBox2" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:text="Font Typeface"
        android:id="@+id/textBox3" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:text="Font Typeface"
        android:id="@+id/textBox4" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is my LogCat:

```
11-17 09:58:20.940    2593-2593/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{it.co.matteopellegrini.android.fontapp/it.co.matteopellegrini.android.fontapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:817)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made
            at android.graphics.Typeface.<init>(Typeface.java:147)
            at android.graphics.Typeface.createFromAsset(Typeface.java:121)
            at it.co.matteopellegrini.android.fontapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4470)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:817)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I tried a lot of times, changed font, changed Java code but I have no solution.

**!!!!!!!!!!! I FIND THAT ONLY IF I USE ANDROID STUDIO THE APP STOPS !!!!!!!!!!!**

**!!!!!!!!!!! IF I USE ECLIPSE IT WORKS !!!!!!!!!!!**

Comment: @GuglieMarcon Should be `My XML`, but not `My HTML`.

Answer (score 0):

Your font file is corrupt or unsupported. You can put it on the SD card and load it from file, to make sure that it's not a problem with your assets.

Double check the extension of the file that it  isn't in caps, For Ex :-  example_font.TTF
Fonts often come seem to come that way and it might be overlooked.

Look at this issue :- https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9904

There is some bug in android when you load fonts from asset folder. Try the above solutions. It will work

Comment: Sorry
!!!!!!!!!!! I FIND THAT ONLY IF I USE ANDROID STUDIO THE APP STOP !!!!!!!!!!!

!!!!!!!!!!! IF I USE ECLIPSE IT WORKS !!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry,
my error was the font folder was **fonts** but i create **font**

Answer (score 0):

your problem is /font_example.ttf"); probably copy your font from window fonts folder and .TTF is uppercase you should change it to font_example.TTF